# How to match Digit with White space and new line in C# regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I Have a register Form and I want to validate phone number in C#,
only digit with white space or newline are accepted in my inputText,How can i create the pattern?
i use `[^\d\s+$]` but it does not work correctly?

Comment: What does your validation code look like?  `[^\d\s+$]` matches anything that's not a digit, a space, a plus sign, or a dollar sign, so if you reject characters that match that, it could work (though I wonder why you'd want dollar signs in a phone number).  But the ^ at the beginning and $ at the end makes me think you are trying to do a pattern for acceptable instead of unacceptable, which would be more like `^(\d|\s)+$`.

Comment: What format for the number (american, french, german, etc..), if you want to try regexp in C# here is a pretty good and fast tutorial with some exemple that should help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You misplaced the anchors `^` and `$` and the quantifier `+`, try

```
^[\d\s]+$
```

The square brackets are defining a character class, you put all characters you want to allow inside. If your character class starts with the `^` its a negated class, means match everything that is **not** inside the class.

`^` anchors the expression to the start of the string

`$` anchors the expression to the end of the string

`+` is the quantifier means here: match from all the characters from the class one or more.

You can find more information about regular expressions on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), maybe the "[quickstart](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)" would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 7):

Try this `^\d[\d\s]*$`

It means the phone number must start with a digit and may continue with any combination of white spaces and digits